# What organic grains can I substitute for self-rising (Gold Medal) flour?

Tags: substitutions, flour, organic, dumplings

My nine (7) year old step-daughter is expecting to help me make Chicken and Dumpling today. I have the recipe for the stew, my question lies in the dumplings:

I am aware that I can replace 1 1/2 cups of self-rising flour by adding 1 1/2 tsp baking power and 1/2 tsp of salt to 1 cup of regular white flour - but I want to avoid the white flour altogether.  **What (organic) grains can I substitute for bleached white flour?**

Answer (score 2):

You might try whole wheat pastry flour, too.  It's usually used in things like pie crusts, and probably would be the closest in texture to white flour.

Any grain other than wheat will not have the same amount of gluten and thus may have a vastly different texture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that King Arthur makes an organic unbleached white flour. It's not like whole wheat, but it's arguably better for you than the other if you are concerned about things being organic.

King Arthur flours are available pretty widely in supermarkets these days.

Comment: King Arthur Flour sells it in organic and regular. http://www.kingarthurflour.com/flours/white-whole-wheat-flour.html It is a whole wheat flour, like many others. The color refers to the color of the bran (which is lighter). In all-purpose flour, a refined flour, the bran is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Unbleached, organic white flour is a good choice. There are also organic "white" whole wheat flours, though like any other whole-grain flour the end result won't be as light or airy.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a chapter in [Super Natural Cooking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1587612755) that details the different types of flours and what to consider when substituting.  I'm pretty sure she gives equivalents so you can choose what levels of gluten/fiber/etc you want, and when the tastes will fit in best.

I'd answer this for you myself, but I've loaned out the book.  :)  When (if?) it comes back, I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

Self-rising flour can be created by combining 1½ teaspoons of baking powder with a ½ teaspoon of salt and 1 cup of all-purpose flour. This substitute equals one cup of self-rising flour.
When substituting whole-wheat flour for all-purpose flour, 1 cup and 2 tablespoons of whole-wheat flour is equivalent to 1 cup of all-purpose flour.